# EF : Select Row With Id and Include newly added row as per page Size

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am Implementing a paged search result, where the Filter can have multiple parameters like Search keyword, Date, Id of the Row, Added by etc.

for eg.

If a user entered the Session Id = 10 , then the paged Result will Include the first Result as Session Id and Rest will be Recently added rows.

Suppose there are 15 IDs, So the Result should Include 10,15,14,13,12..

```
 filterQuery.Where(x => x.SessionId == searchSessionId).Take(5)
```

How to Include Rest Rows as per recently Inserted Id?

Comment: sozs but your not making sense... could you re-word.

Comment: @Seabizkit In another words... I want top 4 rows (Order by Id Desc) + 1 Row where ID== passedID , In a Single query

Comment: do them separately and union them. the view will not know and its the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var res1 = filterQuery.Where(x => x.SessionId == searchSessionId).Tolist();
var res2 = filterQuery.Where(x => something).take(4).Tolist();
var res3 = res1.Union(res2);
```